# Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined?

Tags: jquery

This has to be something simple I'm overlooking but I keep searching for solutions and I'm coming up empty. I have this:

```
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#email").blur(EmailCheck);
function IsEmail(email) {
  var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/; 
  return regex.test(email);
}   

function EmailCheck() {
    var Emailvr = $('#email').val();
    if(isEmail(Emailvr)){
        //Good Email
        $('#email_validate').html('<img scr="/img/accept.png"> Good Email');
    }else{
        //Invalid Email
        $('#email_validate').html('<img scr="/img/error.png"> Invalid Email');
    }
}       
});
</script>
```

It's basically just using the regex to test the email and updating a div with the results. I keep getting a "Uncaught ReferenceError: IsEmail is not defined" error in the firebug console. Any ideas what it could be? Thanks.

Comment: IsEmail(email) != isEmail(Emailvr)

Comment: Typo, try `IsEmail` as JavaScript is case-sensitive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is case-sensitive so `isEmail` is not the same as `IsEmail`.

Comment: Thanks. Knew it was something stupid.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a case anomaly.
In one it's `IsEmail` and the other it's `isEmail(`

The below should work.

```
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#email").blur(EmailCheck);
function isEmail(email) {   
    var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
    return regex.test(email); 
}   

function EmailCheck() {
    var Emailvr = $('#email').val();
    if(isEmail(Emailvr)){
        //Good Email
        $('#email_validate').html('<img scr="/img/accept.png"> Good Email');
    }else{
        //Invalid Email
        $('#email_validate').html('<img scr="/img/error.png"> Invalid Email');
    } 
    }
});
</script>
```